# The best way to send hundreds of http requests from c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to find the best (fastest) way to send hundreds of http requests to various endpoints. I'm getting some information from my database and I need to send start sending it to all subscribers as soon as possible.

I tried to use TPL Dataflow with action block like:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Subscription>(
                data => PostHttp(subscription),
                new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                {
                    BoundedCapacity = 100,
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100
                });


private async Task PostHttp(Subscription sub)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Processing on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                var result = await Process(sub);
                Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode + " thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

And it works quite nice but I can see that my computer is only using 10 threads to start sending data even though I set MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 100.

Is there any faster way for doing that?

Comment: Please format your code, its unreadable

Comment: Firstly, tasks arn't threads, and async isn't parallel. Secondly, MaxDegreeOfParallelism is a limit, not a suggestion of how many threads to use. Thirdly, your code is fine, and there is no inherent reason it couldn't spin up 100 truly async io bound workloads. The problem is (however) whatever it is you are doing in `Process` and we cant see it. its likely fake async, not completely io bound, or something else we cant see

Comment: Also, this could just be a problem with what you are considering a thread, and why, and how you are figuring it out. A true async io bound call doesn't use any threads perse. its a callback from the operating system on an IO completion port

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you should investigate message queue solutions.

Comment: @RandySlavey thanks, do you have any link for inspiration?

Comment: I've used RabbitMQ (https://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Comment: @randySlavey ok and then you have a lot of agents that receive messages from queue and make http request yes? Nice but I assume taht there is a limit on message size and those packages of data to be senat van be quite big.

Answer (score 0):

1 thread `!=` 1 fetch at a time.

I don't know if this is the best way, but one simple way is to use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8).

```
var urls = ...

using var client = new HttpClient();

var tasks = urls.Select(url => client.GetStringAsync(url)); // No error handling for brevity
string[] contents = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

## Test

Let's take it for a spin.

```
public async static Task Main(string[] args)
{
   var urls = Enumerable.Range(0,1000)
        .Select( i => $"https://duckduckgo.com/?q={i}&format=json&pretty=1&kp=-1");

   using var client = new HttpClient();
   var d = new ConcurrentDictionary<int,int>(); // key: threadId, value: requests done

   var tasks = urls.Select( async url => 
   {
       var content = await client.GetStringAsync(url); // No erro handling for brevity
       d.AddOrUpdate(key: Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, 1, (key, count) => count + 1);
       return content;
   });

   var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
   Console.WriteLine($"Done: {sw.Elapsed}");

   foreach( var entry in d) Console.WriteLine($"T{entry.Key} fetched {entry.Value}");
}
```

### Output

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
Done: 00:00:03.0456601
T17 fetched 203
T18 fetched 167
T19 fetched 159
T22 fetched 139
T25 fetched 77
T26 fetched 96
T28 fetched 159
```

---

More reading: [How to extend the async walkthrough by using Task.WhenAll (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-extend-the-async-walkthrough-by-using-task-whenall).