# Fastest way to perform 1000's of HTTP request in C#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to find the fastest way of making 1000's of web request to just get the ping response, if the website is up it will simply print "Good - link" otherwise it will print "bad - link"

This is my function to iterate through each link :

```
    public static void readFile()
    {
        // Read a text file line by line.  
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        int cpt = 0;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            statusSite(line);
            cpt++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nThere is {0} sites", cpt);
    }
```

This is my function to send a request and wait for response :

```
    public static void statusSite(string site)
    {
        
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

        //Pass the handler to httpclient(from you are calling api)
        var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        try
        {
            var result = client.GetStringAsync(site).Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"Good - {site}\n");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Bad - {site}\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58868844/6803592

Comment: you are blocking your method, if you use `result` in an async method it will block your thread, that is why your method is slow

Comment: Check this video, he does something similar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2moh18sh5p4

Comment: Firing off 1,000 requests "just to get the ping response" is nonsense: you only need a few, at most, for that - it sounds more like you're trying to build a DDoS tool...

Comment: @Dai I'm not building a DDos tool and it would be nonsense to do so on a simple computer, I will store the valid website on another text file and perform operations with it + i'm not performing the request on a single website if you read my post twice

Comment: You used "website" in the singular form, not plural - but I'll give you a pass if you're not a native speaker.

Comment: In order to check whether a site exists or not (or is it available or not) it is enough to issue only a HEAD request (if it is supported by the website).